# phpinfo() shows wrong location for php.ini

Tags: php

`phpinfo()` show `php.ini` location as **/usr/local/zend/etc** where as the actual location is **/etc/php5/apache2** . How do i fix this.

I am trying to debug drupal from eclipse ide .. so i have installed zend debugger plugin .
Now i have to edit php.ini and add the following code

```
zend_extension=full_path_to_zend_debugger_extension^gt;
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1  
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=allowed_hosts
```

So before editing the php.ini, I am just using `phpinfo()` to find the location of `php.ini`. But it shows me some location where php.ini doesn't even exists.. please help

Comment: maybe you're running zend server ?? and you whant apache2 instead ? what's wrong with the first location ?

Comment: It don't show wrong location it loads ini from that zend folder.

Comment: @poelinca,@ arma : there is no zend folder in /usr/local.. so how come it shows that the location /usr/local/zend/etc contains php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

`phpinfo()` shows the php.ini file that is loaded by the version of PHP loaded by apache. You may have php.ini files in other locations, but it's the one that reported by phpinfo() that is loaded (and used) by apache.

What are you trying to do? We can help you "fix" that problem.

Comment: @JAB, Blair is correct.  If the php.ini location provided by `phpinfo` displays a different location than the one you're using, then you are indeed editing the wrong file.  Many versions of PHP *can* operate properly without a php.ini, so if it's missing, you can easily correct this.